# $product->save() taking 4 seconds to save one simple product in magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento2, programmatically, create-product

I have below code with Image Upload which is working fine...but it takes 4 seconds to save one simple product....my store have more than 25000 products. It takes more than 4/5 hrs to create/update the products...
please help...

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$_product->setName('Test Product');
$_product->setTypeId('simple');
$_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
$_product->setSku('test-SKU');
$_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$_product->setVisibility(4);
$_product->setPrice(array(1));
$_product->setImage('/testimg/test.jpg');
$_product->setSmallImage('/testimg/test.jpg');
$_product->setThumbnail('/testimg/test.jpg');
$_product->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
        'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
        'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        'qty' => 100 //qty
        )
    );

$_product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change mode from "UPDATE ON SAVE" to "UPDATE BY SCHEDULE" (System / Index Management)

And after saving the products, run full reindex for all indexes.

Comment: after saving the products, ran full reindex for all indexes..
it takes 9 second for simple product...I want to setup cron for product creation ..
it will run for more hours ..

I want to add/update 15.000 products within some minutes by cron ...